# How can I edit symlinks?

Tags: filesystems, symlink

My basic understanding of a symlink is that it's a special file, a file that contains a string path to another file. The kernel's VFS abstracts a lot of that away but is there any reason why symlinks seem to be impossible to edit?

In other words: Can I edit a symlink? If not, why not?

---

I do understand that there are various ways of *replacing* symlinks (two alternatives are currently in the answers section) but it would be interesting to get an explanation on why replacement seems to be the only way to deal with symlinks. Why can't you just change where they point?

Comment: Your understanding is a bit limited; the only reason it's called a 'file' is because there's no better word for it.

Comment: Unlike the embarrassing atrocity that is the windows variant, posix-style symbolic links operate on/in the filesystem layer itself. The only way to edit one would be to edit the filesystem directly -- and it's generally not worth it.

Comment: @Shadur .lnk files are not really symlinks to begin with (and NTFS _has_ had proper symlinks since Vista); they're more like shortcuts for executing commands, whether that is changing to a specific folder or starting a program with specific arguments and with a certain CWD.

Answer (score 56):

Given that `-f` just does a silent replacement, you [can do an atomic replacement with `mv -T` (-T makes it work even if /loc.../link is a directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727280/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-symlink-without-deleting-it-first/1727609#1727609):

```
ln -s /location/to/link linkname
# ... 
ln -s /location/to/link2 newlink
mv -T newlink linkname
```

`linkname` is accessible throughout the process.

Comment: That does get you the atomic replacement, though you still are doing a replace rather than edit ( new link has a new inode number ).

Comment: @psusi I completely agree, it's just a technically slightly better option than the other answer in some scenarios.

Comment: If you're redirecting the link to another destination then changing it's inode number seems like a small change.

Comment: That assumes `linkname` is not a symlink to a directory. Use the `-T` option to `mv` if on GNU or `-h` if on FreeBSD to avoid that. Note that like `ln -sf` that does not preserve the permissions of the link (on systems where they are significant).

Comment: Another solution for change symlink for directory is to use `-n` options e.g.: `ln -sfn DESTINATION_DIRECTORY LINK_NAME` . Read more on http://askubuntu.com/a/186227/69004

Answer (score 31):

If by edit, you mean to change the file it points to, then yes you can:

```
$ ln -s .bashrc test
$ ls -al test
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pascal pascal 7 2009-09-23 17:12 test -> .bashrc
$ ln -s .profile test
ln: creating symbolic link `test': File exists
$ ln -s -f .profile test
$ ls -al test
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pascal pascal 8 2009-09-23 17:12 test -> .profile
```

The `-f` parameter (`--force`) when passed to ln it causes it to call the `unlink()` system call right before `symlink()`

Taken from the following [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466566/can-you-change-what-a-symlink-points-to-after-it-is-created).

Comment: I think it's questionable if this can be regarded as "edit", since unlink();symlink(); is not atomic, so there is a tiny tiny amount of time during which the link does not exist.

Comment: @mauro.stettler Yes, you are right. But I guess that this depends on your perspective. If you take only the end result into account, then maybe you could consider it as edited, no other things considered.

Comment: The quoted section from the Unix Time Sharing System paper describes _hard_ links. These are entirely different from the symbolic links (symlinks) the OP asked about.

Comment: Note that it assumes `test`'s target is not a directory. Otherwise `ln -s -f .profile test` would create a `.profile` symlink in that directory. GNU `ln` has a `-T` option to avoid that.

Answer (score 10):

Symbolic links need to be modified atomically. If you're halfway through writing them, they won't work.
The content of a symbolic link is pretty small (at most 4095 characters on Linux: the maximum length of a path to a file), so there would be little point in editing part of a symbolic link at the kernel level. Therefore the kernel does not offer any interface to edit a symbolic link, only an interface to create a new one, the `symlink` system call (plus the generic interface `unlink` to remove any file).

The `symlink` system call only creates a new symbolic link, it does not remove any existing file. This is annoying, but consistent with other system calls to create files such as `open` (which can create a new file or truncate an existing file, but not replace an existing file by a newly-created file) and `mkdir`.

In the shell, as [you've discovered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88824/how-can-i-edit-symlinks/88829#88829), while you can't replace a symbolic link atomically with the `ln` command (`ln -sf` unlinks the previous file then creates the symbolic link), you can do it by first creating a symbolic link under a temporary name and then moving it into place.

```
tmp=$(TMPDIR=$(dirname -- "$link") mktemp)
ln -sf -- "$target" "$tmp"
mv -f "$tmp" "$link"
```

Comment: `mv -f` (like `ln -sf`) will not do what you want if `$link` points to a directory. GNU ln and mv have a `-T` for that. `mv` (rename system call) will _always_ change the inode of `$link` while `ln -sfT` (unlink+symlink) might reuse the same.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, there's no built-in command to edit an existing symbolic link. It can be easily achieved with a few short commands.

Here's a little **bash/zsh function** I wrote to update an existing symbolic link:

```
# -----------------------------------------
# Edit an existing symbolic link
#
# @1 = Name of symbolic link to edit
# @2 = Full destination path to update existing symlink with 
# -----------------------------------------
function edit-symlink () {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Name of symbolic link you would like to edit:"
        read LINK
    else
        LINK="$1"
    fi
    LINKTMP="$LINK-tmp"
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
        echo "Full destination path to update existing symlink with:"
        read DEST
    else
        DEST="$2"
    fi
    ln -s $DEST $LINKTMP
    rm $LINK
    mv $LINKTMP $LINK
    printf "Updated $LINK to point to new destination -> $DEST"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but you “answer” is only remotely-related to the question asked.

Comment: Hi @user2233709 - the user's question "**How can I edit symlinks?**" was clearly answered in the first sentence as well as by providing a solution. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Did you really read the question? It’s about whether it is possible to **modify** a symlink, rather than **replace** it. Your proposed “solution” is a script that **replaces** a symlink.

Comment: Saying that this answer “is only remotely-related to the question asked” is unduly harsh.  blizzrdof77 says that it’s impossible to do what the question asks for; [that is](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5347/23408#5350 "“That is not possible” is a valid answer") an [acceptable answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3767/23408#3768 "Is stating that OP’s technique is doomed considered not an answer?").  “Your proposed “solution” … **replaces** a symlink.”  The same is true for all the other answers (except for the one that ‘‘actually shows’’ how to edit a symlink, which is wrong).

Comment: The bad news is that this is just a more verbose, less careful version of [Gilles’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89821/23408).

Answer (score 2):

Assume linkname exists as the result of having done (in the past):

```
 ln -s   /the/path/to/a/file   linkname
```

Then, there are three ways to change the symlink:

- Use ln with `-f` force and even for directories `-n` (inode could get reused):

  ```
  ln -sfn /some/new/path linkname
  ```
- Remove the symlink and create a new one (even for directories):

  ```
  rm linkname; ln -s /some/new/path linkname
  ```
- create a new symlink, then `mv` it (atomic change even for directories):

  ```
  ln -s  /some/new/path newlinkname
  mv -fT newlinkname linkname             # linkname remains after the command
  ```

Answer (score 1):

one can edit the target value using 'rename -s'. an absolute path or an expression can be used.

synopsis:

```
rename -s old_target_or_expression new_target_or_expression link_name
```

example

```
$ ln -s /home/sr/tmp/bla foo # create a symlink
$ ls -l foo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sr sr 16 Jun  4 14:41 foo -> /home/sr/tmp/bla
$ rename -s /home/sr/tmp/bla /home/jn/tmp3/blabla foo # replace the target using the absolute path
$ ls -l foo # it works!
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sr sr 20 Jun  4 14:43 foo -> /home/jn/tmp3/blabla
$ rename -s jn/tmp3/ mr/tmp4/ foo # replace the target using an expression (only a part of the string)
$ ls -l foo # it works again!
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sr sr 20 Jun  4 14:44 foo -> /home/mr/tmp4/blabla
```

man rename

```
-s, --symlink
           Do not rename a symlink but its target.
```

Answer (score 0):

## with [Vifm](https://wiki.vifm.info/index.php/Main_Page)

Vifm the file manager has a default key mapping (shortcut) to change where a symlink points to:

<kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>

The mnemonic is **c**hange **l**ink.

[Here's](https://vifm.info/cheatsheets.shtml) a cheetsheet that includes this mapping.